# Validation and update of an existing record in MongoDB - better approach

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-validator

I am writing REST API using Node, Express and MongoDB-Mongoose (newbie alert :). There are separate routes to create and update a document in the collection. I use express-validator to validate the request body. This works while creating and saving a new record. While updating an existing document i only want to validate changed properties and then update it. I can populate the request object with changed and unchanged values, re-run the validation (reuse from create) and update the record. However, i would like to know if there is a better approach?

Comment: The server can only know if some fields are changed in the update request if it pulls the saved document and compares it with the given document in the request body, this would mean adding an extra query to the route and I think that's unnecessary(if this is the only reason you are fetching the saved document). I would suggest you send your update query even with the fields that are unchanged(it is still the same as the previous value), MongoDB won't bother updating those field and if it does, it won't affect your app in any way.

Comment: @OTZ Thanks for the reply. This is first time i am writing REST API so making sure to implement best practices. I also want to know more about managing user login sessions, storing in db, refreshing tokens etc. but probably i should first give it try with what i know, i think. Anyways thanks for answer.

Comment: Yeah, it is important to ensure "best" practices most especially if you are not the only one working on the project. Best practices come in many forms, however, this is a repository you can always reference as a guide: https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices. As for user session, DB logics and other concepts associated with REST APIs, there are tons of resources out there explaining those concepts, however, if you face trouble with any of them, you can always drop a Q here in SO and we would try our best to help out.

Comment: @OTZ The guide link you shared is a goldmine. Again, thank you so much.